# Databricks model deployment to AWS Sagemaker -- No module named docker error

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr, mlflow, mlops, aws-databricks

I am trying to deploy a dummy model to AWS Sagemaker using Databricks and MLflow.

According to this [documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#mlflow-sagemaker-build-and-push-container), it builds a new MLflow Sagemaker image, assigns it a name, and push to ECR.

However, when I run the following lines of code in a Databricks notebook:

```
%sh
mlflow sagemaker build-and-push-container
```

I get the following error:

```
/databricks/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py:2309: UserWarning: Virtualenv support is still experimental and may be changed in a future release without warning.
  value = self.callback(ctx, self, value)
2023/06/12 16:22:04 INFO mlflow.models.docker_utils: Building docker image with name mlflow-pyfunc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python3/bin/mlflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/sagemaker/cli.py", line 605, in build_and_push_container
    mlflow.models.docker_utils._build_image(
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/models/docker_utils.py", line 224, in _build_image
    _build_image_from_context(context_dir=cwd, image_name=image_name)
  File "/databricks/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/models/docker_utils.py", line 228, in _build_image_from_context
    import docker
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docker'
```

I have tried installing docker by running `%pip install docker` and I have tried Databricks' built-in package manager to install docker (using the UI) but the problem still persists.

Could I please get some assistance trying to figure this out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to attempt this on a *non-managed* instance. Using `%pip install docker` will install the package in whichever virtual environment is connected to your notebook. Also, that command installs a [Python wrapper for docker](https://pypi.org/project/docker/), not the engine itself.

**Quick fix:** provision an EC2 instance, install MLFlow and docker, then retry the process.

Comment: By non-managed instance, do you mean I should attempt to do your quick fix outside of Databricks?

Comment: yes, give it a go in [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) for example.